# How to align a Widget within a Column?

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

I want to align my button to the right. Right now I am accomplishing it with a Row that has `mainAxisAlignment` set to`MainAxisAlignment.end` like in the example below. However that seems not a good way because it is a lot of code and I don't think that is the way of doing it.

I already tried the `Align` widget, but that is not working. I guess because it is not expanding the inner widget and therefore the `Alignment.centerRight` is doing nothing.

**The code I use right now:**

```
new Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  children: <Widget>[
    new FlatButton(
          onPressed: _navigateToPreparationStepsWidgetClicked,
          child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(
                'View Preparation Steps'.toUpperCase(),
                style: new TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              new Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right)
            ],
          ))
  ],
)
```

What is the proper way to align e.g. a `Button` within e.g. a `Column`?

Comment: it depends of the parent,  what do you need exactly ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On closer inspection, it's because your button has a row in it. A row by default expands to take up as much space as possible it seems. So when you align your button to the right, it is doing it but the button itself takes up the entire row. If you changed the colour you'd see that more easily. The simple answer is to set mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min on the row in your button.

This works just as expected for me:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(child: Text("Default"), color: Colors.blue, onPressed: () {}),
            Align(
              child: FlatButton(child: Text("Left"), color: Colors.red, onPressed: () {}),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            ),
            Center(child: FlatButton(child: Text("Centered"), color: Colors.orange, onPressed: () {})),
            Align(
              child: FlatButton(child: Text("Right"), color: Colors.green, onPressed: () {}),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            ),
            Align(
              child: new FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      'View Preparation Steps'.toUpperCase(),
                      style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    new Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right)
                  ],
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                ),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Which results in this:

[image: Screenshot of column with aligned items]

Comment: It works - with your button, but not with mine.. Any idea why?

Comment: ah give me a sec.

Comment: My guess is that the row causes this problem. I need a way to place a button right or left next to the text. Is there a better option than a row? In android with java there is a option for a button which makes it really easy.

Comment: Yes, it's because your button has a row in it. A row by default expands to take up as much space as possible it seems. So when you align your button to the right, it is doing it but the button itself takes up the entire row. If you changed the colour you'd see that more easily. The simple answer is to set mainAxisSize to `MainAxisSize.min` on the row in your button.

Comment: That works! Can you add that to your answer? Then we can delete the comments and i can give you the correct answer mark.

Comment: There we go. Added the explanation to the answer, although I'd already added the code =).