# Unable to Align widget Using Align() Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, alignment, flutter-layout

i am new to flutter and i Need help with align widget
Here have used alignment center for the TabBar widget and
alignment bottomRight for Text widget
and i didnt get the correct result here.

**This is the Output image:**

[image]

**Source Code:**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return SafeArea(
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
          body: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Align(
                *[**alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,**][1]*
                child: Text("data"),
              ),
              Align(
                ***alignment: Alignment.center,***
                child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxWidth: 300,
                    maxHeight: 60,
                  ),
                  child: AppBar(
                    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                    bottom: TabBar(
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.directions_car,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxHeight: 100,
                  maxWidth: 100,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: So where you want to show your text data? bottomRight means at the end of screen

Comment: yea, and the TabBar to be in center

Answer (score 0):

For that please remove the `mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.min` into the column widget.

Comment: if you use Stack instead of Column then Align widget is work. in the Column widget you can just set items in a que not in random place

Comment: thank you so much it worked      btw i followed this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883341/how-to-align-a-widget-within-a-column#) he worked it out with the column but it didnt work out for me

Comment: He set all the widgets in the cue so it work for him not for you.